# Is there anyway I can read the configured vxlan VNI and vxlan port for calico CNI plugin in Kubernetes Cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, calico

I have a Kubernetes cluster with Calico Networking and vxlan mode enabled. I want to know what is the VNI and vxlan port number being used by the CNI. I know I can get it by capturing traffic and looking into the packet. But I wanted to know if there is a way to get these values through kubectl or any specific API which I can use in python or go client for kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no single API for checking those values.

Those VXLAN settings are controlled by `vxlanPort` and `vxlanVNI` which are described here:
https://docs.projectcalico.org/reference/resources/felixconfig

And as described in https://docs.projectcalico.org/reference/felix/configuration, a felixconfig value can be defined in one of 4 places:

1. Environment variables (on the calico-node daemonset)
2. The Felix configuration file (not typically used in a kubernetes cluster)
3. Host-specific FelixConfiguration resources (`node.<nodename>`).
4. The global FelixConfiguration resource (`default`).

That's also the order of precedence, i.e. env vars override everything else, etc.

The only other way to check would be to get the logs for the calico-node pod in question - calico-node pods output their detected configuration at start of day in one of their first few logs.